# Substitute yogurt powder for confectioners sugar when making royal icing

Tags: substitutions, yogurt, icing

When making treats, I try to make them as appealing as possible and like to decorate them.  I have been looking for an icing recipe that can be used for decoration that doesn't include sugar.  Most of the ones I have found call for yogurt, however they do not harden.  I recently purchased a mix which was yogurt based which worked really well however could get costly if I do a lot of treats.  I was wondering if I used a royal icing recipe and substituted the confectioner's sugar in the recipe with yogurt powder, would it work?

Comment: I'm tempted to say: there's only one way to find out!

Comment: Sorry Pat, long time ago this community decided that pet food questions are off-topic. I personally disagree and find your question reasonable, but I am bound by the existing policy and have to close the question :( For what it's worth, I would say that the answer is no - it doesn't matter that they look similar, yogurt powder and sugar powder have completely different physical properties and won't behave the same way in a recipe. You cannot use them as substitutes. I can't tell you how to develop a suitable glaze, but just using yogurt in a sugar recipe won't work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about creating food for pets, not for humans. Here the relevant Meta thread, http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1108/would-a-question-regarding-making-homemade-pet-kitten-cat-food-be-considered-o/1109#1109.

Comment: @Pat in the time since the decision was made, our network for question sites got a Pets site added, http://pets.stackexchange.com/. I would suggest that you go there and ask them what pet-friendly ingredients will look like a glaze; they may know something about it. (Don't ask straight about the substitution, this would be off-topic for them, just ask them what pet food would be a good fit).

Comment: Couldn't we convert this question so it is for humans (and dogs) too?

Comment: I edited the question to remove the referral to pets. I think that pets or no, it's an interesting substitution idea.

Comment: Removing all references to dogs means that we should agree with any solutions which will work for humans and not for dogs, which is probably not what the OP intended. But now that sourd'oh invested the work in editing, I will reopen and we'll see what will come out.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder what those yogurt covered peanut contain? They are sweet but a similar setting agent minus the sugar might do the trick? e.g Agar agar